# Изменить логику установки значения

Tags: javascript, html, knockoutjs

Работаю над следующей задачей:
Есть свойство, на которое мы реализовали dataBinding

```
InputTemperature: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(0);
OutputTemperature: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(0);
```

А эти свойства связаны с элементами, на которые повешены стили из MDL. То есть там, например, над слайдером, ещё есть скрипт, обновляющий представление. И вот если обратиться к элементу

```
$("#slider")[0].MaterialSlider.change(value)
```

он отработает правильно. Только knokout этого не делает - он обращается к input и изменяет value. Естественно, скрипты mdl не отрабатывают и отображается всё "через жопу".

Вопрос: как перегрузить метод обновления? и с какой стороны это лучше сделать? проход по подписчикам с определением нужного? или на уровне Input - повесить дополнительные действия на событие изменения?
Проблема в том, что в последнем случае придётся писать очень много кода, так как такой элемент управления не один.

Может, есть какое-нибудь решение "из коробки" на такой случай ?

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону механизма custom binding у knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html.

Comment: Да, то, что надо. Спасибо